# Optimistic number of people chatting

Tags: bug, chat

Sometimes we see at the right side something like

[image: People chatting]

I clicked it and got to the meta chat room. Then I see for instance this

[image: Last posted message]

**So the first screen shows 37 people chatting in 9 rooms in the last 60 minutes.**

I visited **all** rooms and I found only **1** chat message within the last hour in a single room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You visited all rooms *you could see*.

The number is correct, it's just that [there's a bunch of people](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=active&sort=activity) who are active in private rooms (in this case, Stack Exchange company internal rooms, which are hosted on Meta's chat).

Comment: From the user's perspective, lots of invisible people are chatting silently. Should they be reflected in the number?

Comment: It's debatable, but I've mentioned that before and it hasn't changed, so I believe it's considered [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Otherwise it'd have to account for whether or not you were someone who could see those rooms for it to be accurate, which I imagine is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: If we're not going to make the number in public chat rooms *the only number* reported, we can always make it *another number* reported.