# Confusion between data and links pertaining to ASE chat rooms, and those pertaining to Stack Exchange chat rooms

Tags: bug, chat

I just entered an ASE (Aviation Stack Exchange) room (after not being in any chat room for about 10 minutes)<sup>1</sup>, and I saw a message on the right-hand side of my (computer) screen saying "There are other rooms, with 47 users currently talking in 41 rooms.".  But when I clicked on the message, it took me to the ASE chat room home page.  There were 8 active rooms, and only 2 active users.

But up at the top of the ASE chat room home page, there were tabs labelled "users (47)", "rooms (41)", and "faq".

When I moused over those tabs, I see tags saying "47 users active in last 60 minutes", and "41 rooms active in last 120 minutes".

From the ASE chat room home page, if I click on the "users (47)" tab, I get directed to the Stack Exchange users page (which has more than 47 users total, but presumably only 47 active in the last 60 minutes), not the ASE users page.

If I click on the "rooms (41)" tab, it appears that almost nothing happens.<sup>2</sup>  I stay on the ASE chat room home page, which (as of right now) has only two active users, and 8 active rooms.

If I click on the "faq" tab, I get directed to https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq, which is not surprising as ASE has no specific faq relating to chat rooms.

It appears that there is some confusion between data, and links, pertaining to ASE chat rooms, and those pertaining to Stack Exchange chat rooms.  Some data pertaining to Stack Exchange chat rooms is being shown on the ASE chat room home page, in a way that makes it look like it pertains to ASE chat rooms.  And the same for some links.  And some of this confusing data is also sometimes displayed to an ASE user who is in an ASE chat room.

Additional data: for comparison, I just looked at the [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=chemistry.stackexchange.com) chat room home page.  (I'm not a member of Chemistry Stack Exchange).  Many of the same problems are occurring there.  One difference, though, is that when I hit the "rooms" tab, it took me to the *Aviation Stack Exchange* chat room home page!

Also, I went into a Chemistry SE chat room, and saw the tag saying "There are other rooms, with 47 users currently talking in 41 rooms", and clicked on it, and it took me to the *Aviation* Stack Exchange chat room home page. So something is definitely not working right.

It's becoming clear that the way these features work has some connection to the SE sites one has recently visited, but not in a way that makes sense.

Footnotes:

1. I don't know whether that detail is relevant, but it doesn't happen *every* time I enter a ASE chat room.
2. Actually, *something* does happen-- a tag line under the title changes from reading "a list of rooms about Aviation Stack Exchange (more sites…)" to reading "a list of rooms about The Stack Exchange Network (more sites…)".  But the the title remains "Aviation", showing the ASE logo, and the rooms displayed are still the ASE rooms.  So something is obviously messed up here.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be migrated too-- perhaps it is something that ASE has no power to fix-- if so, that's fine--

Comment: StackExchange as a platform is responsible for all of this, we at Aviation do not control this and as such I'm going to migrate this to the main StackExchange meta so you can get answers to your question(s). Please post future platform queries/discussions there.

Comment: Using Chrome on a PC laptop, if it matters at all.

Comment: The chat "remembers" your selections, this includes when you visit lobby of specific site. To see chats of all sites, click the "all" link. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXwlu.png). Then the numbers will match, and you'll get to the "all" chats when closing and opening your browser again. Unless of course you click specific site chat link again.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars -- ok, but there's still more to it then that.  Even if we forget about the numbers entirely, the question describes how the tabs at the top of the chat room page for the specific SE site (Aviation SE in this case) are not consistently working as one would expect.  See also footnote 2.

Comment: As far as the numbers go, these questions appear to be related:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268462/413377,    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191642/413377  But is *not* just a question about the numbers;

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars -- OK, first of all I didn't realize that ASE chat rooms were a *subset* of Stack Exchange rooms.  But why is, when I'm in the ASE chat room home page (so the "site" tab is selected), does the "Users" tab function so different from the "Rooms" tab?  The former takes me out to a page showing *all* SE Users actively talking, while the latter keeps me on the Aviation Stack Exchange chat rooms home page.  Does that make sense?  Seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Chat is ancient, so quirks are expected. In this case, number of users and active rooms are not being filtered by site, only the rooms you see in the "lobby". The "filter by site" feature appears to have been added as some afterthought, without much planning, and that's the result.

Comment: Lovin' the DV's as always, but this is not *only* a question about the "numbers" of users and rooms.  If you read through the entire question, you'll understand that.