# Possible bug--why is a recently-frozen chat room not showing on front page of chat rooms, sorted by "activity" ("show frozen/deleted rooms" selected)?

Tags: support, chat

Specific sub-site where I'm noticing this: Aviation Stack Exchange

Possible bug--why is a recently-frozen chat room not showing on front page of chat rooms, sorted by "activity", with the "show frozen/deleted rooms" option selected?

Here is the specific chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142952/discussion-between-quiet-flyer-and-paul-smith

Here is the permalink to the final message https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63243613#63243613

That message was from "feeds", saying "This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity".  That message was posted March 25.

Here is the permalink to second-to-last message https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63153996#63153996

That message was posted March 10, 15 days before the final message.

Here is a link to a listing of all the chat rooms in "Aviation Stack exchange", sorted by activity, with the "show frozen/deleted rooms" option selected -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=aviation.stackexchange.com

Attached below is a recent (March 27) screenshot of the upper part of the first page of the listing of all the rooms I see on Aviation Stack Exchange chat.  You can see that the room in question is not showing as one of the frozen rooms, which have a grey background.

(If it were showing, the last activity should be showing as from March 10, about 17-18 days ago depending on exactly when a new "day" starts-- and note that the closing message from "feeds" is not counted in computing the last activity.  No frozen room with similar last activity is showing, and I doubled-checked the frozen room with last activity 21 days ago and it's not that one either.)

## Why is this room not showing?  Is this a bug in the system, or is there something that I am not understanding?

[image: screenshot of chat rooms listing]

[image: alternate screenshot of chat rooms listing]

Comment: posts by "feeds" (aka all users with a negative userid) are not considered activity. That also explains why you can't use an rss feed to keep a room unfrozen.

Comment: @rene -- thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.  In fact my question contains that information.

Comment: did you choose the correct "site" for the room you're expecting to see? the screenshot seems to indicate no

Comment: The "a list of rooms about..." line in your image links to the stack exchange network, you can click "more sites" to filter it to aviation (this might just be yet another quirk of the old chat search)

Comment: This seems like the exact type of situation where using the "filter rooms" capability would be useful. Given that you know you're one of the main people for whom the room was created (i.e. your username is in the tile), it would be reasonable to [filter on "quiet flyer"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people&filter=quiet+flyer&page=1&nohide=true&host=aviation.stackexchange.com), which shows the room you desire as the second one in the list. [Even when not limited to just Aviation, it's second](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=people&filter=quiet+flyer&nohide=true).

Comment: @KevinB -- I've rediscovered exactly how to replicate the bug that triggered your comment https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387911/possible-bug-why-is-a-recently-frozen-chat-room-not-showing-on-front-page-of-ch#comment1293690_387911 -- all I have to do, while on the Av. SE chat room home page, is click on the "rooms" tab.  The labelling changes from what we see on the second screenshot of this answer to what we see in the first, but *all* the rooms displayed on *all* the pages remain exactly the same, Av. SE rooms only.  Anyway, yes, I did choose the correct site.

Comment: @KevinB I described the same phenomenon (bug) in Footnote 2 here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386832/413377 .  That's not really what the *current* question is about, but just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Re "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. "  -- well, that's not true.  Rather, an explanation has been offered as to how the system sorts the chat rooms-- criteria *other* than latest activity are actually dominant.  But yes, the question has been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat rooms come in groups. Roughly these categories and always in this order:

- The first group are rooms created by users / moderators.
- The second group are rooms created by importing comments from under a post.
- The third group are rooms created by "start a new room with this user"

Within each group the rooms are sorted by activity. The room you're looking for falls into the second group. So it is unlikely it will ever be on the front page if you also show deleted/frozen rooms.

Comment: Got it-- that's helpful to know.  (Oops, editing to reverse what I just said) -- So, if I want a chat room to tend to show higher on the list, its best to create the room myself, rather than to keep a comment chain going till the system gives me the option to automatically move to chat.